# c# group by alphabets

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I need to show list of authors group by last name first letter.

```
e.g.
A
  Kim, Ami
  Dim, Amaiar
  jin, Amairaz

B
   Bin, Bom
   Kin, Bomo

C
   Cin, Ci
   Con, Co

....
```

Could some one please help me what's the best way to solve the above problem?

Comment: What is the input ? What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group by, use [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx), I assumed you want the output to be ordered ([OrderBy](http://www.dotnetperls.com/orderby)), Change the `GroupBy` expression to match your exact requirment:

```
List<String> names = new List<String>{"Bill", "Mark", "Steve", "Amnon", "Benny"};
foreach(var g in names.GroupBy(name => name.First()).OrderBy(g => g.Key)){
    Console.WriteLine(g.Key);
    g.OrderBy(name => name).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
}
```

Will output:

```
A
Amnon
B
Bill
Benny
M
Mark
S
Steve
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393.aspx) extension method over Linq object to get the desire result.

```
 List<string> firstNames = new List<string>(){ "Ami", "Amaiar","Amiraz","Bom","Bomo","Ci","Co" };

 var groups = firstNames.GroupBy(x=>x[0]);

 foreach (var element in groups)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", element.Key);

    foreach (var word in element)
       Console.WriteLine("    {0}", word);
 }
```